# Syntax Error no lex/flex

Tags: bison, flex

Porque a minha reconhecedor flex/lex exibi um erro de syntax quando tento reconhecer o texto **ESCREVER 1;**

```
%{

#include "gram.h"

int yyerror(const char *s);

%}



/* letras [A-Za-z]+ */


/* id     ({letras})({letras}|{digito})* */

%%

"ESCREVER" {return   ESCREVER; }                                
"TERMINAR" {return TERMINAR; }

[0-9]+     { yylval.num =atoi(yytext);
             return NUM; }


[A-Za-z0-9]* { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);
                return TEXTO;}


"/" | 
"-" |
"+" |
"*" |
"=" |
.          {return yytext[0];}
[ \n\t]    {  }


%%


int yywrap(){ return 1; }
```

Comment: Qual o erro que retorna ?

Comment: Syntax Error , já alterei a gramática , mas mesmo assim o erro continua a persistir

Comment: só vendo a gramática: a mensagem de erro "erro de syntax ..." é provavelmente emitida pelo parser (yacc/bison) que está a invocar este analisador lexico. Palpite: símbolo `';'` na gramática do yacc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na frase `ESCREVER 1;` o espaço `' '`está a fazer matching com a regra

```
.   {return yytext[0];}
```

que está antes da regra que processa espaços e que apanha string com o mesmo comprimento. Isso retorna o símbolo `' '` que deve causar erro gramatical.

Sugestão 1: põem a regra dos espaços antes da regra que inclui o `.`

Sugestão 2: em vez de

```
"-" |
"+" |
"*" |
"=" |
.          {return yytext[0];}
```

usa

```
[\-+*=]   {return yytext[0];}
```

colocando apenas os símbolos especiais previstos na gramática

Comment: já funciona obg